# At very high frequency (700 kHz), an AC circuit has a voltage reading 10 times the EMF, why is this?

Tags: voltage, ac, transformer, frequency

I've set up an experiment in which I vary the frequency of an electric signal using a waveform generator. The experiment is testing a transformer, but I've encountered a problem on the primary circuit of the transformer.

Starting with a total circuit potential difference of 4 V at 50 Hz, I increased the frequency to see what would happen to the voltage.

At very high frequencies (600 kHz to 1.1 MHz), I get a voltage reading that increases to a value of -44 V which is very strange being that the current is alternating, there should be no minus value.

The voltage reading drops to 0 at about 500 kHz, and then suddenly I get a reading as I further increase the frequency. After peaking, the reading then falls again at the maximum frequency i can generate (1.1 MHz).

The voltage is read using digital multimeters, I've tested these and used lots of different meters, all give the same readings.

Can anyone explain to me this strange result?

Comment: How do you get a -ve voltage reading when measuring AC voltage? Most DVMs will only measure AC properly at 50 Hz or so.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to say about your experiment.

1. Did you think about what would be the expected outcome of your experiment? What do expect from the output voltage? If you didn't think about it, then every result will be surprising. Use the scientific method: always start from the theory, make an hypothesis and then test it with the experiment.
2. What's your test setup? Have you just connected the multimeter to the secondary of the transformer? Note that the load will affect its behavior.
3. You're making the readings with a multimeter, so make sure that you're measuring AC (maybe you're doing that, it's not specified) otherwise you won't obtain a stable and meaningful measurement.

Comment: You seem to be missing the primary issue - as pointed out by Leon.

Comment: @ChrisStratton that explains one thing, but the most important (IMO) is knowing what to expect from the experiment, which is not obvious in this question.

Comment: (1) The aim of the experiment initially was to see what happened to the voltage across the secondary coil of the transformer if the frequency of the current in the primary coil was changed. (2) The power source and frequency generator are setup in series to the transformer. The voltmeter is set up parallel to the transformer as it is measuring potential differece, it it this meter giving the strange reading, and yes it definetly was a minus value, i couldnt comprehend why this would be seeing as the current is AC and the multimeter set to read AC? all other readings up to 500kHz were positive

Comment: @clabacchio have you any answers for me?? I was definetly using a multimeter set to measure AC voltage, all equipment was tested beforehand